# Pulling data from one database to another MySQL & PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a database based on information from other databases. All of these are hosted on the same server.

The database I am creating would have rows with something like this where data is generated when the data was last pulled:

| Database_ID | Sale_Count | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-05-03 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-05-03 |
| 1 | 6 | 2021-05-04 |

The databases I would be pulling from would look something like this:

Database 1:

| Sale_Count |
| --- |
| 6 |

Database 2:

| Sale_Count |
| --- |
| 4 |

Unfortunately, I don't have a significant amount of SQL experience and trying to understand how I would approach this. I understand how to join tables together when they are in the same database but am not familiar with joining two tables on different databases.

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: SO where are you going to get the dates from?

Comment: Are you confusing the terms "database" and "table" by any chance? You need to be clear about what is actually what. Then [edit] the question use the correct terms and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0):

To access another database, you just need to qualify the table name.  So if you are connected to database dbA and you want to select, join, etc table tbl in database dbB, you just use dbB.tbl in your query instead of plain tbl.

If you have separate users for different purposes, you may need to grant select access to the table to the user you are connected as.